# Simulate Data Protection on iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, data-protection

I am trying study the Data Protection Process on iPhone Simulator, but i am failing at the initial step.I created a DB File and added it to the Application Resources. During the Application Launch i copy this file to the Application Folder.

Then i do this:

```
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:fileAttributes ofItemAtPath:appDBPath error:&error]) {
        //handle error
    }
```

But when i check the file attributes after this, i do not get the key NSFileProtectionKey

Am i missing something obvious in it? Do we have to add any Framework for Data Protection?

Or is it that this can only be tested on the device?

I need to get it done quickly.. Please help me guys :(

Comment: Are you getting an error from your setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error: call?

Comment: no its executing without error... but this key/value pair is not added in the files attributes